# Using @react-native-community/netinfo in a class, possible?

Tags: react-native, hook, react-native-community-netinfo

I'm trying to add to my application a function to add a view indicating to the user that he is disconnected from the internet network.

So I went to @react-native-community/netinfo to set it up but I quickly found myself confronted with the difficulty of using hooks and the related error: "*`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component`*".

So how to integrate @react-native-community/netinfo on an application that is class based?

I would like to change the state of the application when the change of connection state is detected, to show or not the view indicating the disconnected state.

**Your help would be greatly appreciated!**

This is what I used for my tests:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Guess (from the error message) you are declaring the listener in the class itself which is wrong.

Just move the listener declaration to the `componentDidMount` hook and unsubscribe from it in `componentWillUnmount` hook, it should work as you would expect.

If u need a full example leave a comment and I'll provide it to you. Cheers

Comment: Thanks you for your response and sorry for the delay of mine !
After a few tries, I finally managed to reach my goal using your solution.
Thank you!

Comment: @Tarik Chakur if you can share an example, that would be great

Answer (score 1):

There is a hook in the library that you can use out of the box, is called useNetInfo() and you can use it like this:

**EDIT:**

You can read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61068807/usetheme-equivalent-for-class-component/61377032#61377032) in order to use this hook into a class based app. This is similar to netInfo.

[Example from git, react-native-community](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo)

```js
import {useNetInfo} from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

const YourComponent = () => {
  const netInfo = useNetInfo();

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Type: {netInfo.type}</Text>
      <Text>Is Connected? {netInfo.isConnected.toString()}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

**EDIT 2:**

Full example:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView, Text } from 'react-native'
import { useNetInfo } from '@react-native-community/netinfo'

export default class Home extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            netInfo: undefined
        }
    }

    setNetInfo = netInfo => {
        this.setState({netInfo})
    }

    render () {

        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                <SetNetInfo setNetInfo={this.setNetInfo} />
                <Text>Hello world</Text>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }

}

const SetNetInfo = ({ setNetInfo }) => {
    const netInfo = useNetInfo()

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setNetInfo(netInfo)
    },[netInfo])

    return null
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response !
I finally managed with another solution, but I really thank you for taking the time to post your examples, I'm pretty sure I'll use them afterwards, especially if I want to display a clear login status :)